# Stripe BillingPortal NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm facing difficulty in integration of the [Stripe customer billing portal](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/create) using NodeJS. Please, help.

**Error:**

```
Cannot read property sessions of undefined.
```

Comment: You need provide more info. Can you share the code?

Answer (score 3):

This error sounds like one that would be thrown by a line of code that looks like

```
var session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
  customer: 'cus_XXYYZZ',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/account',
});
```

either because you've not imported the Stripe NodeJS library correctly, or you are using a version prior to [8.45.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#8450---2020-04-22), which is the first version of the Stripe NodeJS library to support the Customer Portal.

You should also make sure to closely read and follow the [Customer Portal guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal) in the Stripe docs as there are some nuances that you should understand.

Comment: In my case this was indeed a version issue. I switched git branches and didn't run npm install. Once I did, this error went away