# billingPortal does not show up as function for Stripe API

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe API to generate a redirect link for a user to edit their payments.
Documentation and steps: https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/integrate-customer-portal#start

My question is similar to [Stripe BillingPortal NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830618/stripe-billingportal-nodejs) except that question is unresolved and I will provide more details.

Since I'm using NextJS, I import Stripe as recommended by the official [NextJS Stripe guidance](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/29a913467ff7e5b40f539bfb32d21aee1da976ca/examples/with-stripe-typescript/utils/get-stripejs.ts)

When I call the `stripeJS` object, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sessions')
```

```js
const stripeJS = await getStripeJs();

const session = await stripeJS.billingPortal.sessions.create({
  customer: 'some_customer_id',  // Redacted 
  return_url: 'https://example.com/account',
});

console.log(session.url);
```

I know my import is correct because when I `console.log(stripeJS)` my `stripeJS` object, I get the following:

[image: screenshot]

**What's strange is `billingPortal` is not found on this list of functions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stripeJS seems to be a client-side object, when it has confirmXXX methods, and uses a Publishable Key. To create Billing Portal session, you need a server-side API, or the NodeJS [Stripe SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) which will use a Secret Key.